# Why are there no annotations for init block in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, annotations

Is it true that in `Kotlin` there is no `AnnotationTarget` that is applicable to the init block?

And if it is correct then why is it so? To me it looks exteremely strange.

I've tried different `AnnotationTarget`s but none of them helped. Then, I've tried not to use `@Target()` annotation at all and it didn't work out either.

Comment: What would that be useful for?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819/5133585 Please clarify what kind of answer you are looking for when you asked "why".

Comment: @Sweeper I'm new to annotations in Kotlin and annotations in general. So, during my studing of this topic I came across such a restriction and thought maybe I don't know something or maybe there is a hidden reason for that. 

Thank you for pointing out that "why" questions are not answerable! I can reformulate my "why" question: "What are the reasons for not allowing annotations above `init` block?"

Comment: Because `init` is essentially just the body of the primary constructor, which **can** be annotated.

Comment: @Slaw You can have multiple `init` blocks, but not multiple primary constructors. I think annotating init blocks would feel more like annotating a code block, rather than annotating a whole constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin is designed to be able to interoperate with Java. Kotlin code must be able to be compiled into .class files. The class file format doesn't have "init blocks", so annotations on init blocks cannot be encoded into a class file.

This means that annotations on init blocks, if they were supported, must have `AnnotationRetention.SOURCE`. This is similar to annotations on expressions, which *are* supported. (`AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION`).

This means only annotation processors would be able to make use of these annotations. You can't access them with reflection or by inspecting the class file.

What would an annotation processor do with an ***init*** block, specifically? I can't think of anything that must be done to init blocks, that can't be done to other code blocks. You can already annotate code blocks by using a `AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION` on a `run { ... }`,

```
class Foo {
    val x: Int
    init {
        @MyAnnotation run {
            // ...
        }

        // if you need to initialise a val
        @MyAnnotation
        x = run {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Sure, if you have lots of `val`s to initialise and you want to do annotation processing on each of them, you would need to write `@MyAnnotation` a lot of times. In that case, it could be better to design it so that you apply an annotation to the whole class for all the init blocks to be processed, and use another annotation to mean "opt out".

In general, I think init block annotations adds very little.

Comment: They manage to "encode" `property` annotations in the class file (via a synthetic static method, if I'm not mistaken). I think if they wanted to, they could find a way to do the same for `init` blocks. But properties actually exist after compilation (from Kotlin's perspective, anyway). Do `init` blocks continue to exist as a "thing" after compilation?

Comment: @Slaw well they could add a dummy method for each init block and annotate that, but it cannot contain the code in the init block because you cannot assign final fields in methods. So all the information you can get is “how many init blocks there are and which ones are annotated”. Unlike properties, from which you can get quite a lot of useful information from (name, type), doing the same for init blocks seems rather useless.

Comment: @Slaw Having `BINARY` or `RUNTIME` retention for init block annotations is kind of useless in the first place. No code can directly "use" an init block. They don't even have names. And if init blocks were to be represented in the reflection API, there is only *one* thing you can do with them - `annotations`. I think this is also for parity with Java's init blocks. Java's init blocks can't be annotated, and no one ever felt the need to do so, as far as I can find.

Comment: Right. I agree with all that. But I suppose I don't view `init` blocks in Kotlin as the equivalent to Java's instance initialization blocks. Even though you can have multiple of them (which I actually either didn't know or forgot), I still view `init` as the body of the primary constructor. So, if I was to justify not having annotatable `init` blocks, it would be because you "can" annotate them—via the primary constructor. But, of course, I'm not a Kotlin language developer; I don't know their true reasons.